# Change ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: regex, preg-replace, ereg-replace

How would I change

```
$output = ereg_replace("<script.*</script>", "", $output);
```

to preg?

```
 I tried $output = preg_replace("/<script.*</script>/", "", $output);
```

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry, messed up formatting

Comment: @minitech sorry format was messed up

Comment: You might have to escape the <. It has special meaning in Perl regular expressions, so just replace `<` with `\<` both times.

Comment: Oh, and the `/` before `script` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `/` as the delimiter, you *must* escape every occurence of `/` within the pattern, or its recocnized as delimiter itself and everthing following will be used as modifiers (which will probably fail).

```
"/<script.*<\/script>/"
```

or you make your life easy and just choose a different delimiter. I prefer `~`, because it occurs in patterns quite infrequent

```
"~<script.*</script>~"
```

Update: See comments for the description, what happens here

```
"~<script.*</script>~siU"
```

Comment: @ridgerunner: The question was about the syntax, not the semantic of the pattern. But reflecting the meaning of the pattern you are right of course; Ive added it.